# UISearchDisplayController delegate method is not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I'm trying to add an `UISearchBar` to a table view I have defined in a ´nib´ file. I added a Search Bar and Search Display Controller in IB, linked the search bar outlet, and added this to the view controller's '.h' file:

```
@interface SearchListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

Also, I've implemented the following delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString 
{
   [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
   [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption 
{
   [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
   [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
   return YES;
}
```

I find that `shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` method is called, but however `shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:` method is never called, so my table view data is not reloaded with search results... what could I be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: only putting `UISearchBarDelegate` in to .h class not enough you need to set it like `yourserchbar.delegate=self;`

Answer (score 4):

You have to set delegate to self.

```
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

[UISearchDisplayController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: NOTE: UISearchDisplayDelegate is deprecated since IOS 8. Instead use UISearchDisplayController (as Rajneesh071 mentioned)